# Button click event not firing on android device when soft keyboard is displayed.

Tags: angular, keyboard, event-handling, responsive

I am building a form on angular 4. On android, lets say I am editing a textbox, the soft keyboard is on the screen. Then I swipe to the bottom of the screen where the submit button is. When I click , the keyboard hides itself but the event on the button is not fired. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

When you use FormsModule and ReactiveFormsModule, by default angular disables the default form submission.

You can wire this up by assigning a method to an output event on the form element.

```
<form (submit)="onSubmit($event)" [formGroup]="myformgroup">
  <input type="text" formControlName="myformcontrol"/>
</form>
```